# Can't write into iomem region in qemu using gdb

Tags: qemu

I'm trying to add an new device in the qemu.

In the respective cpu file, used sysbus_mmio_map to set the base address.

```
sysbus_mmio_map(SYS_BUS_DEVICE(&s->brif), 0, BASE_ADDRESS);
```

In the newly created device file,

```
memory_region_init_io(&s->iomem, obj, &ops, s, "brif", SIZE);
sysbus_init_mmio((SYS_BUS_DEVICE(obj), &s->iomem);
```

The ops has the corresponding read and write handlers.

My read handler is getting called when I access the IO memory region using gdb, but my write handler is not getting called when I write to the IO memory region using gdb.

What am I missing?

Update: I do get the write handlers if I write to the IO memory region from the code running inside the guest, the problem is only when I try to access from the gdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive it's just a bug. Se this [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1625216) (with a patch included).